# How to pass information from one page to another with drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

I have a custom entity named **Application** that has an **Entity Reference** field named **Product**.

When I am on an Apllication page and click on a **Product** to see it, I would like to know that I come from the **Application** page and know its **ID**.

This would allow me to display information from the **Application** page on the **Product** page.

But how to do it ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a form you can set $_SESSION for send data form one page to another,

```
class MymoduleSessionCounter {
  function increment(Request $request) {
    $session = $request->getSession();
    $value = $session->get('mymodule_count', 0);
    $session->set('mymodule_count', $value + 1);

    return $value;
  }
}
```

In a form method get the request from getRequest():

```
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $session->set('mymodule_form_value', $form_state->getValue('value'));
  }
```

If you are using link you can send ID in query string and get data on page.

please let me know if any more details you need.

Comment: How to use sessions in D8

Is a very vague question, so the answer will be equally vague.

Drupal 8 uses Symfony's HttpFoundation Session Management, so that's where the API is documented.

If you look in core.services.yml you can find that Drupal's wrapper is in

session_manager:
  class: Drupal\Core\Session\SessionManager